# Cross Origin resource sharing enabled video Safari 7 canvas

Tags: html, video, canvas, safari, cors

I've built a javascript application which lets you take a snapshot of a video.

The video is hosted by amazon s3, and the bucket has cross origin resource sharing headers set to allow all.

The video tag has the crossOrigin="anonymous" attribute set.

The application works fine in Chrome and Firefox without errors.

When I call toDataURL() on the canvas, I get the following message

```
Unable to get image data from canvas because the canvas has been tainted with cross-origin data.

SecurityError: DOM Exception 18: An attempt was made to break through the security policy of the user agent.
```

What other steps do I need to take to get this to work with both a remotely hosted video and and toDataURL()?

Answer (score 2):

Short of proxying the video from your server, there is nothing you can do here.  Safari does not yet support the `crossOrigin` attribute on an `HTMLVideoElement`.

Comment: Can you elaborate on how I would proxy the video to my server, its a rails app hosted on heroku?

Comment: Add some code to your server that handles a GET request for the video.  This handler will then stream the response from the cross-origin server for the video.  Instead of pointing at the cross-origin URL, post to a path on your local server that is setup to proxy the remove video in this manner.  You'll need a server on the same domain as the one hosting your page for this to work.

Comment: I addressed this concept in another CORS-related question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18113025/486979

Comment: Would this technique work with video? Its taking me some time to conceptualize how I could do this with my rails setup.

Comment: The file type is irrelevant.  It's all just bytes. Client-side: The `src` attribute of your `<video>` or of the `<source>` children of your `<video>` points to your local server.  When the page loads, a GET request will be sent to your server.  Your local server makes the request to the cross-origin server for the video/resource, and streams that response as the response to your client's request.