# canvas.toDataURL() gives "Security Error" in IE 11

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, canvas, html5-video

I'm working on the browser-based tool for media distributors that require some manipulation with video.

I have HTML5 video player with video loaded from another domain (ex. http://video.com). Domain returns the following headers for the video (tries `...-Origin` with * and with specific domain name):

```
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
```

The `video` tag is like this:

```
<video crossorigin="anonymous" src="http://video.com/video.mp4"></video>
```

JS I run is the following:

```
        // meida is a reference to <video> tag
        var
            imgData,
            width = media.videoWidth,
            height = media.videoHeight,
            canvas = document.createElement("canvas"),
            context = canvas.getContext('2d');

        canvas.width = width;
        canvas.height = height;

        context.fillRect(0, 0, width, height);
        context.drawImage(media, 0, 0, width, height);

        imgData = canvas.toDataURL('image/png'); // line where IE throws DOMException named 'Security error'
```

The code works in all browsers except IE family. I've tried it on IE 11.

I understand that in this case canvas becomes tainted while it should not.

Does anybody know any way to make it work? I saw some workarounds for images but it doesn't work in my case with `video`.

PS: I've seen the answer [Canvas.toDataURL() working in all browsers except IE10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18112047/canvas-todataurl-working-in-all-browsers-except-ie10) but it is quite old and is related to images. I hope things changed since then.

Comment: Following this document https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy I found out a workaround. It is possible to set up domains like http://tool.com for the application and http://tool.com:8080 for videos then the IE assumes video to be from the same location as the tool allowing screen capturing.

Comment: @stephaska, if it does work you should add it as an answer and accept it

Comment: it doesn't actually solves the problem. This is workaround with a huge limitation - both hosts should be on the same IP. So I don't think it is an answer unfortunately.

Comment: Our customer insisted that we have support of the feature in IE11 so I ended up creating backend streaming proxy.

Answer (score -1):

I was trying to export pdf of page which includes highcharts.
I was getting same problem with IE when trying to load svg data on canvas, same security error.

I fixed this issue using [canvg.js](https://github.com/canvg/canvg)

just include canvg library files,

Add canvas on html page,

```
<canvas id="canvas" width="1000px" height="600px"></canvas>
```

use below method,

```
canvg(document.getElementById('canvas'), xml);
```

It worked for me in all browsers including IE.

Comment: The question is pretty clearly about video and your solution definitely doesn't answer it. Ps: svg tainting the canvas in IE is an entirely different issue and has nothing to do with CORS.

Answer (score -1):

By using fabric js "Security Error" in IE 11 will be gone.

```
    var
        imgData,
        width = media.videoWidth,
        height = media.videoHeight,
        canvas = document.createElement("canvas"),
        fabCanvas  = new fabric.Canvas('c'),
        context = fabCanvas.getContext('2d');

    canvas.width = width;
    canvas.height = height;

    fabCanvas.fillRect(0, 0, width, height);
    fabCanvas.drawImage(media, 0, 0, width, height);

    imgData = fabCanvas.toDataURL({format: "png"});
```

Comment: context is not used, fillRect and drawImage should be on context instead of canvas. But more importantly: this does not work... Security Error still happens