# Chrome HTML5 <video> request - no cookies sent

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, cookies, html5-video

I'm working on HTML5 video player which should play video streamed from a server that requires authentication. Authentication is done using PHP. In general the code looks like this:

```
<!-- http://localhost/video.php -->
<video preload="none" crossorigin="anonymous">
<source type="video/mp4" src="http://localhost/video_proxy.php">
</video>
```

So before get to /video.php user has to log in. Log in information is 'stored' in PHPSESSID cookies.

The problem is that when sending a request to `http://localhost/video_proxy.php` Chrome doesn't send any cookies with that request. The result is that `http://localhost/video_proxy.php` redirects to `/login` and nothing is played of course.

I was not able to find amy documentation or description of this behaviour so I'm curious how can I make Chrome to send cookies with the video request.

PS: I've checked the same scripts in Firefox and IE and that browser's behaviour is ok - cookies are sent and everything works.

PPS: I've also tried to disable all Chrome extensions, reset settings to defaults. And I've tried it on several colleague's computers - same behaviour.

Comment: is the video on the same origin as the page itself?

Comment: The request is sent to the same server. HTTP file is 'http://localhost/video.php' and video file is 'http://localhost/video_proxy.php'

Comment: have you tried without the `crossorigin` attribute (I admit I'm guessing)

Comment: my guess is based on [CORS settings attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/CORS_settings_attributes) - which states that `The "anonymous" keyword means that there will be no exchange of user credentials via cookies, client-side SSL certificates or HTTP authentication`

Comment: Yes, that was the case. Thanks. Now am a bit confused with the purpose of the `crossorigin` attribute. I use it to enable CORS usage. Without it set to `anonymous` other browsers will not start playing video from the other domains. It is also confusing that in other browsers it sends cookies.

Comment: I thought you said it was same domain ... other domains, use crossorigin, same domain, do not ... other domains only works if they do not need any credentials, of course

Comment: as the page and the video url are same domain, try (with the `crossdomain` attribute) setting `src="/video_proxy.php"` - see if that works - maybe Chrome sees the full hostname there and just decides it must be cross domain request

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the crossdomain attribute accroding to [CORS settings attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/CORS_settings_attributes) -

> The "anonymous" keyword means that there will be no exchange of user credentials via **cookies**, client-side SSL certificates or HTTP authentication

I would think that for same domain the crossdomain attribute would be ignored, which seems the case in Firefox and IE

However, based on the fact that you stated your page and video URL are same domain, it seems Chrome has a different idea on the use of the `crossdomain` attribute compared with Firefox and IE

Comment: I use the same page to show videos from other domains and from the same domain based on some criteria. That's why there was a `crossorigin` attribute. I'm actually solving the following issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30101143/canvas-todataurl-gives-security-error-in-ie-11 by proxying video. Now I set `crossorigin` attribute only for appropriate videos and it works ok.

Comment: so as `video_proxy.php` either gets the video locally or from elsewhere (depending on some criteria as you say), as far as the **browser** is concerned, the video comes from same domain, so no need at all for the `crossorigin` attribute

Comment: No. In the `<video>` tag based on if it is IE or not I put either direct link to the video or proxy script on the same server as from which page was loaded. So as an additional step I either add or not the `crossorigin` attribute.