# No php script can be run on server while there is another long-lasting php script running

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, apache, http

I have a long-lasting PHP script running on server. It streams video to `video` tag from server (don't ask me why I do it :-) ). It can run for tens of minutes.

The problem is that at the same time I want to send the request to server using AJAX and it doesn't happen before the long script stops.

I've investigated the issue a bit more and I found out strange things.

- While the long-lasting PHP script is running I can not call any PHP scripts (either AJAX or not) from the same browser.
- Meanwhile from other browser server is accessible without problem.
- Non-php assets (images, videos) can be accessed without problems.
- In case video is played directly from .mp4 file the problem doesn't exist. AJAX requests to php can be processed while video is played.

I'm curious what could cause this issue. From what I see it could be combination of server and browser configuration.

My question is why it happens and how can it be solved? I want to be able do the AJAX requests to the server while other PHP script is running in the same browser.

Here is an example of 'stuck' requests. First request is the video, second one is the AJAX which I want to send and it doesn't go anywhere before 1st is completed.
[image]

As soon as 1st is completed the 2nd one is done immediately. 
[image]

Web server is Apache 2. It was reproduced in IE and Chrome.

Ajax request is sent using just normal jQuery's $.ajax() call.

Here is the request and response information for the video request that blocks AJAX request.

```
Request GET /portal/portlet/index/id/671/call/proxyVideo?entityId=1 HTTP/1.1
Accept  */*
If-Unmodified-Since Fri, 24 Apr 2015 08:18:29 GMT
If-Match    "f91b54d-514740a87ff40"
Range   bytes=360448-261207372
User-Agent  Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko
Referer http://mm.mac/content
GetContentFeatures.DLNA.ORG 1
Pragma  getIfoFileURI.dlna.org
Accept-Language en-US
Accept-Encoding gzip, deflate
Host    mm.mac
Connection  Keep-Alive
Cache-Control   no-cache
Cookie  PHPSESSID=41821op72k2s24mfrsbn5gad64


Response    HTTP/1.1 206 Partial Content
Date    Tue, 01 Dec 2015 13:39:31 GMT
Server  Apache/2.4.16 (Unix) PHP/5.6.13
X-Powered-By    PHP/5.6.13
Expires Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Cache-Control   no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Pragma  no-cache
Last-Modified   Fri, 24 Apr 2015 08:18:29 GMT
ETag    "f91b54d-514740a87ff40"
Accept-Ranges   bytes
Content-Length  260846925
Access-Control-Allow-Methods    GET
Content-Range   bytes 360448-261207372/261207373
Keep-Alive  timeout=5, max=100
Connection  Keep-Alive
Content-Type    video/mp4
```

Comment: `don't ask me why I do it :-)` - Automated piracy?

Comment: If you are using the default session storage then sessions are written to a file. The long lasting request will create a lock on the session file preventing other requests. You could move your sessions to a database or use `session_write_lock()` in the long lasting script when you no longer need the session information, thus freeing the lock

Comment: Its called `session_write_close()` ?

Comment: http://www.genericarticles.com/mediawiki/index.php?title=How_to_optimize_apache_web_server_for_maximum_concurrent_connections_or_increase_max_clients_in_apache

Comment: @vanSteinenGroentjes That is correct. Typo from my side :)

Comment: >Automated piracy? Not really. Have to solve this issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30101143/canvas-todataurl-gives-security-error-in-ie-11 by this ugly way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Session lock

This issue could be caused by a **session lock**. When the long lasting php script uses sessions with `session_start()`, the process locks the session file on the server till it is finished. Blocking all other PHP processes that are trying to open the same session file.

This is why you see this behaviour in the same browser, but not on another machine or different browser (since the session is different).

The solution to your problem is to use

```
session_write_close();
```

Whenever you do not need to write to the session. You can still read from the session variables when you called this function but for another write to a session variable you need to open the session again using `session_start()`.

You can read a lot of this problem [here](http://konrness.com/php5/how-to-prevent-blocking-php-requests/).

#### An example: (from the linked page)

```
// start the session
session_start();

// I can read/write to session
$_SESSION['latestRequestTime'] = time();

// close the session for writing
session_write_close();

// now do my long-running code.
// still able to read from session, but not write
$twitterId = $_SESSION['twitterId'];

//when you want to write again do session_start() before and close after.
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer.

Answer (score 0):

Only 1 PHP script can access the same user session at a time
, all other scripts will wait until the first script complete.

This is becouse session file write lock.

Solutions:

1. do no use session if you do not need one (in your long script)
   or
2. Call session_write_close () as soon as possible to unlock session file
   http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-write-close.php