# Your browser has tainted the canvas in internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, svg

I am creating a project using AngularJS. In my project, I am downloading the pdf which has some data and canvas. This pdf is complete on all browsers except internet explorer. In the Internet Explorer am getting `Your browser has tainted the canvas in Internet Explorer`

In my pdf canvas is not drawing.Here is my code:

```
    var canvasArr = [];
    $("svg").each(function(index) {

        arr.push(this)
        var parent = this.parentNode;
        var thisData = this
        var svgLength = $("svg").length;
        var id = $(this).attr('id')
        SVG2Bitmap(this, function(canvas, dataURL) {

            canvas.id = "canvas_" + id;
            canvasArr.push(canvas)
            parent.replaceChild(canvas, thisData);
            var image1, image2, image3,image4,image5 = null;
             var p2 =  new Promise(function (resolve, reject) { 

                 html2canvas(html, {
                      onrendered: function(canvas) {
                          image1 = canvas.toDataURL();
                          resolve(image1)
                      }
                  });
             });
              Promise.all([p1,p2,p3,p4,p5]).then(function(image){
                var docDefinition = {
                    header: {
                      margin: 10,
                      columns: [

                      ]
                  },
                    content: [{
                        image: image[0],
                        width: 500,
                    }],
               }) 
              pdfMake.createPdf(docDefinition).download('price-calculation-' + $scope.getDateTimeFormat("YYYY-MM-DD-hh:mm:ss") + '.pdf');
         })

        })
```

Here is the library which is using to convert SVG to a canvas.

https://github.com/Kaiido/SVG2Bitmap

Comment: [There are lots of questions/answers](https://www.startpage.com/do/dsearch?query=Your+browser+has+tainted+the+canvas+in+internet+Explorer&cat=web&pl=ext-ff&language=english) about this error. Maybe one of them will help.

Comment: This is probaly a duplicate of : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18112047/canvas-todataurl-working-in-all-browsers-except-ie10 You might want to simply "not" pull data from the canvas. Just show it once, and then don't interact with it anymore with your code, or host the pdf on the same domain. Perhaps a simple routing script on the server JUST for IE.

Answer (score 2):

It was already mentioned in the comments, but this does seem to primarily be an issue with Internet Explorer. You *say* that your PDF canvas is not drawing, but the library that you're using *is* drawing on a canvas. They even have comments in the code highlighting some of the [issues around Internet Explorer](https://github.com/Kaiido/SVG2Bitmap/blob/master/SVG2Bitmap.js#L646).

As mentioned in the linked question, you might [follow the advice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18112047/canvas-todataurl-working-in-all-browsers-except-ie10#answer-19734516) of one those answers for handling IE issues. That might not actually help though, since its really the library that you're using that is causing the issue.

If you're not looking for a strictly client-side solution, you might also want to consider proxying the URL for the PDF to avoid the issues with IE as well.